# Linux: How to use a file as input and output at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash

I've just run the following in bash:

```
uniq .bash_history > .bash_history
```

and my history file ended up completely empty.

I guess I need a way to read the whole file before writing to it.
How is that done?

PS: I obviously thought of using a temporary file, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: It's because the files get opened from right to left.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146435/how-do-i-sort-a-file-in-place-using-bash-shell

Comment: You have to write the output to a new file in the same directory and rename that on top of the old file. Any other approach will risk losing your data if it is interrupted halfway through. Some tools may hide this step from you.

Comment: Or, `bash` won't put consecutive dupes in its history if you set HISTCONTROL to include ignoredups; see the manpage.

Comment: please consider changing the answer to this one. https://serverfault.com/a/557566/130392

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I recommend using `sponge` from [moreutils](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/moreutils/). From the manpage:

```
DESCRIPTION
  sponge  reads  standard  input  and writes it out to the specified file. Unlike
  a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening the output file.
  This allows for constructing pipelines that read from and write to the same 
  file.
```

To apply this to your problem, try:

```
uniq .bash_history | sponge .bash_history
```

Comment: It's like cat, but with sucking capabilities :D

Answer (score 95):

```
echo "$(uniq .bash_history)" > .bash_history
```

should have the desired result. The subshell gets executed before `.bash_history` is opened for writing. As explained in [Phil P's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/135539), by the time `.bash_history` is read in the original command, it has already been truncated by the [`>` operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections).

Comment: I used this answer to do `echo "$(fmt -p '# ' -w 50 readme.txt)" > readme.txt` today. Was searching around for a long time for an elegant solution. Many thanks, @Hart Simha!

Comment: this clears the file if the command in the `echo` raises an error

Answer (score 17):

Another trick to do this, without using `sponge`, is the following command:

```
{ rm .bash_history && uniq > .bash_history; } < .bash_history
```

This is one of the cheats described in the excellent article [“In-place” editing of files](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/) on backreference.org.

It basically opens the file for reading, then "removes" it. It's not really removed, though: There's an open file descriptor pointing to it, and as long as that remains open, the file is still around. Then it creates a new file with the same name and writes the unique lines to it.

Disadvantage of this solution: If `uniq` fails for some reason, your history will be gone.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that your shell is setting up the command pipeline before running the commands.  It's not a matter of "input and output", it's that the file's content is already gone before uniq even runs.  It goes something like:

1. The shell opens the `>` output file for writing, truncating it
2. The shell sets up to have file-descriptor 1 (for stdout) be used for that output
3. The shell executes uniq, perhaps something like execlp("uniq", "uniq", ".bash_history", NULL)
4. uniq runs, opens .bash_history and finds nothing there

There are various solutions, including the in-place editing and the temporary file usage which others mention, but the key is to understand the problem, what's actually going wrong and why.

Answer (score 6):

use sponge from [moreutils](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/moreutils)

```
uniq .bash_history | sponge .bash_history
```

Answer (score 3):

As an interesting tidbit, sed uses a temp file as well (this just does it for you):

```
$ strace sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' foo    
open("foo", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)       = 3
...
open("./sedPmPv9z", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0600) = 4
...
read(3, "foo\n"..., 4096)               = 4
write(4, "bar\n"..., 4)                 = 4
read(3, ""..., 4096)                    = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
rename("./sedPmPv9z", "foo")            = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
```

Description:
The tempfile `./sedPmPv9z` becomes fd 4, and the `foo` files becomes fd 3.  The read operations are on fd 3, and the writes on fd 4 (the temp file).  The foo file is then overwritten with the temp file in the rename call.

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` script removes adjacent duplicates. With the `-i` option, it does the modification in-place. It's from the `sed` `info` file:

```
sed -i 'h;:b;$b;N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/ {g;bb};$b;P;D' .bash_history
```

Comment: sed still uses the temp file, added an answer with `strace` illustration (not that it really matters) :-)

Comment: @Kyle: True, but "out of sight, out of mind". Personally, I would use the explicit temporary file since something like `process input > tmp && mv tmp input` is much simpler and more readable than using `sed` trickery simply to avoid a temp file and it won't overwrite my original if it fails (I don't know if `sed -i` fails gracefully - I would think it would though). Besides, there are lots of things you can do with the output-to-temp-file method that can't be done in-place without something even more involved than this `sed` script. I know you know all this, but it may benefit some onlooker.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
uniq file 1<> líneas.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A temporary file is pretty much it, unless the command in question happens to support in place editing (`uniq` doesn't - some `sed`s do (`sed -i`)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%!uniq' -cx .bash_history
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` run command
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score -1):

You can use tee as well, using uniq output as input:

```
uniq .bash_history | tee .bash_history
```

Comment: No you cannot do this http://askubuntu.com/a/752451